# Is it possible to remove the YouTube logo from a chromeless player?

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to remove the YouTube logo from a chromeless player?

Comment: Yes. easy. Don't host it on youtube.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't and you shouldn't.

> If you use the Embeddable Player on
>   your website, you may not modify,
>   build upon, or block any portion or
>   functionality of the Embeddable
>   Player, including but not limited to
>   links back to the YouTube website.

www.youtube.com/static?gl=US&template=terms

Answer (score 6):

Now YouTube allows you to remove Logo in embed videos in your website. For this at the end of youtube url in embed vide just add `modestbranding=1`

Detailed explanation avaialble in [How to Remove YouTube Logo on Embed Videos?](http://sansalabs.com/howtoguides/how-to-remove-youtube-logo-on-embed-videos/)

Answer (score 3):

You can, just add the code `?modestbranding=1` : [check here](http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2011/06/next-step-in-embedded-videos-hd-preview.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using the chromeless player, but you don't have to use it. You can stream videos directly by parsing the URL like such: [youtube get_video not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602956/youtube-get-video-not-working/5132711#5132711)

I had to do this to get more direct video access within flash, since you have limited access with chromeless player due to flash's crossdomain.xml

But as far as Youtube's terms go, if you do this you may have to have a link back to the Youtube source, else you risk copyright infringement of sorts, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the youtube logo from the youtube player. But you can do indirect way means you can hide the youtube logo from the display area.

youtube logo height is 50 pixel. So Set your player height is your video height (accepted video display area height) + 100. and set vertical (y axis) position -50 (Minus 50).

Ans just do the masking for the your video display area. So End user will not get youtube logo on your application player. [Please visit this Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496186/how-can-i-remove-youtube-logo-from-the-youtube-player-for-use-in-other-applicati)

Comment: I'm late to the party here but this is explicitly against the YouTube TOS.  Proceed at your own risk with this.