# Embed youtube hiding source / video ID

Tags: video, youtube

Is there anyway to embed a youtube video either with normal embed or using another player to play the youtube video but hide the source of the video.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the [youtube api](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#player_apis) any other way I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the terms and conditions for youtube, particularly point 4C and 4F.

http://www.youtube.com/static?gl=US&template=terms

4C

> You agree not to access Content through any technology or means other
>   than the video playback pages of the Service itself, the Embeddable
>   Player, or other explicitly authorized means YouTube may designate.

4F

> If you use the Embeddable Player on your website, you may not modify,
>   build upon, or block any portion or functionality of the Embeddable
>   Player, including but not limited to links back to the YouTube
>   website.

EDIT: Adding related question.

[Is it possible to remove the YouTube logo from a chromeless player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444710/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-youtube-logo-from-a-chromeless-player)

Comment: is the API not an "explicitly authorized means"

Comment: It clearly is since it is provided by Youtube. I would be careful and read the rest of the terms since, if you are intending to hide the link, there might be something related to the API similar to the Embedded Player. Check the API terms as well.

Comment: Just added a related previously asked question.

Comment: were trying to keep the video just for members, and we dont want them sharing the link, but we need it stored on youtube

Comment: I can't think of a **legal** way you could do this if you are hosting the video on Youtube. You might want to consider getting your own flashplayer for this. There are several on the net. I can check which is the last one I used if you want but note that you will have to host the videos on your own server.